# Line integrals - parametric

Tags: calculus

Compute $$\int_C (xy)^{1/3} ds$$ where $C$ is the curve $y=x^2$ for $0 \le x \le 1$.

How do I find the parametric description for $C$ in the form $r(t) = \left<x(t), y(t)\right>$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you let $x=t$ then $y=x^2=t^2$. So one parameterization is $r(t)=(t,t^2)$ with $0\leq t\leq 1$.